# siunitx explicit-sign not for all numbers in column

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx, booktabs, tilde

One have the table that align according decimal point by siunitx package, and sign before all numbers is tilde (\sim).

How remove tilde for number 7 only, without break the alignment?

(I tried to add ${\sim}$ before all numbers except 7, but the alignment was broken)

Current output:

```
  numbers
   ~22.45
~54567
    ~7
    ~3
```

Target output (without tilde before 7):

```
  numbers
   ~22.45
~54567
     7
    ~3
```

The current code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=7.2, explicit-sign={\sim}]|}
    {numbers}\\ \hline
    22.45 \\
    54567 \\
    7 \\
    3 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You wrote, "I tried to add `${\sim}$` before all numbers except 7". Have you tried replacing `${\sim}$` with `\sim`?

Comment: Note: option `explicit-sign` has been removed since the v3 release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\sim` command is a comparator, not a sign, and I really wouldn't leave it as an add-on. I'd use

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{tabular}{|S[table-align-comparator = false,table-format=\sim5.2]|}
    {numbers}\\ \hline
    \sim 22.45 \\
    \sim 54567 \\
    7 \\
    \sim 3 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `${\sim}$` with `\sim` seems like a good idea.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=7.2, explicit-sign={\sim}]|}
    {numbers}\\ \hline
    \sim 22.45 \\
    \sim 54567 \\
    7 \\
    \sim 3 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```